# ArcGIS The search window doesn't recognize english terms

Tags: arcgis-desktop, search

In ArcGIS 10.4.1 the search window only works in German even though the performance surface is displayed in English.
I downloaded and installed the English version of ArcGIS 10.4.1

Does anybody know why?

Comment: If you launch Microsoft Internet Explorer, what language appears?  Desktop uses IE for certain things.

Comment: Actually Internet Explorer is in German

Comment: Try configuring IE for English and see if that changes the language that appears in the search window. https://pchelp.ricmedia.com/change-internet-explorer-language-settings/

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned in the comments by @Kirk Kuykendall, try configuring Internet Explorer to English to see if that changes the language that appears in the search window.

See **[this link](https://pchelp.ricmedia.com/change-internet-explorer-language-settings/)** on how to change the Internet Explorer language settings.